# Background Videos in HTML Sections

Tags: css, html

Do I need to have my video uploaded on my computer to get it set as a section background, or I could use embedded code for that video?

Comment: Easy way...upload it to YouTube, access it with an iframe, and wrap the iframe in a div with lower z-index than the section's z-index

Comment: Okay, so use embedded code with iframe and wrap it with a div.. got it.. i'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

actually for viewing a video in your webpage , there are two ways:
1) use html5 video tag
2) use flash
**I recommend first one**
you can do this to show a video in background via video tag:
**html:**

```
<section>
      <video autoplay>
           <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
           <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
      </video>
</section>
```

**css:**

```
section{
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
}
video{
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      opacity:0.6;/*optional for a cute view!*/
}
```

this will get you a full screen video that plays after page is loaded
you can set your prefered width or height to section
good luck

Comment: Thank you! Now, (src="video.mp4") is the video that i will have to have in my folder right?